# indexing nodes and links in views

Tags: views, nodes, navigation

I have a content type that contains text, picture and term reference (cat, dog).
I've used views and create a page with cats and a page with dogs.

The problems:

1. I want only 2 pages indexed by Google. The dogs page and the cats page. I don't want Google to index my nodes separately. Now I have one page with all my cats, one with all my dogs ( << the pages that should be indexed by Google and published for the users) and one page for each cat and one for each dog ( << pages that i don't want).
2. On my front page I need a 2 column area : column1, column2. Both columns should contain text and image. ( If I create new content type and then use a view I have the same problem as above.)
   When I click column1 I want to go to cats page.
   When I click column2 I want to go to dogs page.
   How can I assign links different links for the view results? I know I have "Output this field as a link" in "REWRITE RESULTS" but it uses the same link for all views elements. I also know about "Link this field to the original piece of content". But this mean that my info from column1 should be in cats page and from column2 in dogs page. And I only wish to display the info from column1 and column2 on my front page.

How could I solve this ? Which is the best solution in order to create something like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use http://drupal.org/project/node_noindex for noindexing concrete nodes. 
   Or modify robots.txt for excluding count of nodes, `Disallow: /node/`, for example, next help for you: [Robots.txt Tutorial](http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/).
2. Do you mean that clicking on whole column should lead to cats/dogs? If so, create custom template (in Views editing you should see in "Theme:Information" -> "Display output" -> take latest filename and copy source from link. Create this with filename and paste source. Wrap whole code into ....

Comment: 2. No. I want to click on column1 title and go to yahoo.com and on column2 title and to go to google.com. I only know how to redirect both titles to yahoo.com or to the source node. If this requires custom code, can you please be more specific ?

Comment: If these columns are views blocks, just add headers there (in views editing), and add custom links. Then remove title from block, so these will not appear on columns...

Comment: Also..
1. Is this the best practice for doing something like this ? Use views, remove from robots.txt and use something to block users from accessing the link manually? Are there other solutions?